# Magento 2 is not updated when updating custom module

Tags: magento2

I create a custom module for magento 2. When I update the code, the update is not reflected on my shop.

I did set the mode to developer. Clean all the cache bin/magento cache:clean

What is the best practice for this while developing magento module?

Comment: you need to run setup:up command from in your magento root and then flush cache

Comment: After the setup:upgrade I think it might be needed to setup:di:compile depending of what were the changes